# Collecting the weights returned by clients without aggregating them

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow-federated

I would like to know the easiest way to create a model, broadcast it with tensorflow federated, run a cycle and collect the weights returned by clients without aggregating them with the fedavg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TFF provides the [`tff.federated_collect`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/federated_collect) intrinsic for this purpose; it materializes a stream of client data at the server.

One easy way to wire this into the guts of a mostly-existing federated procedure would be to fork [`simple_fedavg`](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/master/tensorflow_federated/python/examples/simple_fedavg/simple_fedavg_tff.py), which I think is a reasonable starting point for working with TFF's lower-level capabilities.

There are a few things to note here. First, no 'production' system of which I am aware supports `federated_collect`. Second, depending on your desire, there is possibly an easier and more straightforward solution: just return the client weights themselves. The TFF runtime will materialize a Python list of client weights (as eager tensors I believe), on which you can perform arbitrary python postprocessing.

To get here from `simple_fedavg`, you would effectively [return the `client_outputs` directly](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/master/tensorflow_federated/python/examples/simple_fedavg/simple_fedavg_tff.py#L127) instead of passing them to `tff.federated_mean`. This would give you the client deltas (IE, the difference between the final client weights and the initial client weights); you could, however, simply modify [`client_update`](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/11e4f632b38745c9b38cc39fa1fe67771c206e77/tensorflow_federated/python/examples/simple_fedavg/simple_fedavg_tf.py#L223) to avoid computing this difference if desired.