# How to inspect client model updates in Tensorflow Federated

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

I've been learning the [TensorFlow Federated](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated) framework recently but have run into a problem. I'd like to look at the trained client weights sent to the central server before aggregation.

For example, in [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/federated_learning_for_image_classification) tutorial, I have access to the state variable:

```
NUM_ROUNDS = 11
for round_num in range(2, NUM_ROUNDS):
  state, metrics = iterative_process.next(state, federated_train_data)
  print('round {:2d}, metrics={}'.format(round_num, metrics))
```

The state variables holds the weights of the central model (created by aggregating client weights). Is there anyway to inspect the weights that were sent by the clients prior to aggregation in TensorFlow Federated?

Thanks, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The `Federated Learning for Image Classification` tutorial uses the [`tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/learning/build_federated_averaging_process) API to construct the training process; looking at the code of how that method aggregates, and plugging something in just before that would work. However! This method is fairly complex as it is parameterized by aggregation methods from [`tff.aggregators`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/aggregators).

To create alternative algorithms, I'd suggest looking at the simpler [federated/tensorflow_federated/python/examples/simple_fedavg/](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/tree/v0.17.0/tensorflow_federated/python/examples/simple_fedavg) implementation. Specially, the average of client updates is computed on [Line 131](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/3357b74e2878b43921d5e92323f2659ece7e08a8/tensorflow_federated/python/examples/simple_fedavg/simple_fedavg_tff.py#L131). Plugging in just before that would be the place to look.

Also see the question [Collecting the weights returned by clients without aggregating them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65772509/collecting-the-weights-returned-by-clients-without-aggregating-them)
, which also explains how to avoid aggregating entirely.